# Rendering polygons with Qgis2threejs?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, qgis2threejs

I have a polygon shapefile cotegorised according to a specific field. I want to present that 3D with the help of Qgis2three.js (sth like that).[image] I have installed the plugin and have chosen the polygon settings from Qgis2threejs window but when I clicked run button the browser lagged (didn't respond) temporarily and then the result windows showed nothing.
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with the zoom ? Sometimes it may happen that the zoom level is not set properly.

If that doesn't work, try the following
 - in the DEM menu, select "Flat plane"
 - In the polygon layers list, with your layer ticked :

- Object type : Extruded
- Z coordinate : relative to DEM ; height = 0
- Height : you field with the z values
- Tick "Features that intersect with map canvas extend"

Just tried in 2.16 and it works just as your asked.

As for the lagging, I always had it for a few seconds, not sure if there is any way of avoiding it.

Comment: I tried this in chrome and it worked. Maybe there is a bug in Mozilla.

Comment: I'm using mozilla too, it works like a charm!

Comment: Are you up to date with the plugin and the browser? 


Also make sure that Javascript is activated and that there is no plugin on mozilla that could block the script running?


Try to expand the layers tab (top right on your second screenshot) to see if the layer is loaded properly in mozilla. 


Last thing I'm thinking of is display your layer as a basis, (DEM-> Display type -> layer image, then select one of your choice.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to NOT use lat lon projections... use projected ones... configure the qgis map to use utms for example... meter coordinates.... and then generate the output in qgis2threejs...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please don't just include what to try, but include how and why.  [Edit] your answer to expand on how to do what you're suggesting, and what it will do to solve the problem.